# Partially viewable bottom sheet - flutter

Tags: dart, modal-dialog, flutter, bottom-sheet

Is it possible in flutter to have the bottom sheet partially viewable at an initial state and then be able to either expand/dismiss?

I've included a screenshot of an example that Google Maps implements.

[image: Bottom sheet example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will be implementing the same behaviour in the next few weeks and I will be referring to the backdrop implementation in Flutter Gallery, I was able to modify it previously to swipe to display and hide (with a peek area).

To be precise you can replicate the desired effect by changing this line of code in backdrop_demo.dart from Flutter Gallery :

```
 void _handleDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    if (_controller.isAnimating)// || _controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed)
      return;

    _controller.value -= details.primaryDelta / (_backdropHeight ?? details.primaryDelta);
 }
```

I have just commented the controller status check to allow the panel to be swipe-able.

I know this isn't the complete implementation you are looking for, but I hope this helps you in any way.

Comment: Didn't realise you had answered this, but I saw the backdrop_demo.dart in the Flutter Gallery and had been using the `_handleDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details)` for my implementation by coincidence! What are the olds. Thanks for posting this and the backdrop_demo.dart.

Comment: When using this modification in conjunction with a GoogleMap underneath then on iOS devices the _handleDragEnd does not get fired once you start swiping down the bottom sheet. Anybody does have a solution for this behaviour?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `DraggableScrollableSheet` widget with the `Stack` widget:

[image: Google Maps Draggable Sheet]

Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/rohan20/869492358cbb15311538f069a0c749af) for the entire page in this^ GIF, or try the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rohantaneja/pen/JjYgPzm).

Here's the structure of the entire page:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomGoogleMap(),
          CustomHeader(),
          DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: 0.30,
            minChildSize: 0.15,
            builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: scrollController,
                child: CustomScrollViewContent(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the `Stack`:

 - The Google map is the lower most layer.

 - The Header (search field + horizontally scrolling chips) is above the map.

 - The DraggableBottomSheet is above the Header.

Some useful parameters as defined in `draggable_scrollable_sheet.dart`:

```dart
  /// The initial fractional value of the parent container's height to use when
  /// displaying the widget.
  ///
  /// The default value is `0.5`.
  final double initialChildSize;

  /// The minimum fractional value of the parent container's height to use when
  /// displaying the widget.
  ///
  /// The default value is `0.25`.
  final double minChildSize;

  /// The maximum fractional value of the parent container's height to use when
  /// displaying the widget.
  ///
  /// The default value is `1.0`.
  final double maxChildSize;
```

Edit: Thank you [@Alejandro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52403709/partially-viewable-bottom-sheet-flutter/62089808?noredirect=1#comment121601194_62089808) for pointing out the typo in the widget name :)

Comment: There's a typo on the first sentence: it's supposed to say `DraggableScrollableSheet` instead `DraggableBottomSheet`. Just in case anyone searches for the wrong one like me ;P.

By the way, I didn't know of this widget. Cool insight!