# How I can add a widget to top of the bootomsheet when scrolling up and hide it behind the bootomsheet when scrolling down

Tags: flutter

I am looking for a way to make it possible to add a widget to Climb to the top of the bootomsheet when scrolling up
and when scrolling down it go down to bottmom behind the bootomsheet like bootomsheet on Google Maps

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52403709/partially-viewable-bottom-sheet-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Use [BottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) class.

There are two versions of it. `showModalBottomSheet` and `showBottomSheet`.

`BottomSheet` is a widget, and you can treat it as another screen, so using `Column` and other widgets you can use to design this screen.

A handy property, in this case, is `isScrollControlled`.

Comment: After I searched on google, i am confused between using BottomSheet and DraggableScrollableSheet

Comment: BottomSheet is like Column i.e. fixed, whereas DraggableScrollableSheet is like ListView i.e. scrollable and not fixed. Column and ListView are only for analogies